C# Exposed Word AddIn not showing
I'm trying to access an exposed function in a Word AddIn using VSTO from a standalone C# app.  I followed the code in How to call VSTO class from other c# project for the accepted solution.
ITestAddin.cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WordAddIn
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public interface ITestAddin
  {
      bool DoSomething();
  }
}

TestAddIn.cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WordAddIn
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class TestAddIn : 
      StandardOleMarshalObject,
      ITestAddin
  {
      public bool DoSomething()
      {
          return true;
      }
  }
}


ThisAddIn.cs

namespace WordAddIn
{
  private TestAddIn testAddIn;

  protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
  {
     try
     {
         if (testAddIn == null)
         {
             testAddIn = new TestAddIn();
         }
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
      }
      return testAddIn;
    }
}

I successfully compiled the code.
Here is the standalone code section
Word._Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word._Document oDoc = new Word.Document();

object addInName = "WordAddIn";
COMAddIn addIn = oWord.COMAddIns.Item(ref addInName);
bool t = addIn.Object.DoSomething();

This throws a syntax error saying object does not contain a definition for 'DoSomething'
I've tried solving the issue and broke everything out to make it extremely simple and followed what was in the example and it still has the error.

Do you get that error at run-time or compile-time? In the latter case, change your code to
object addInName = "WordAddIn";
COMAddIn addIn = oWord.COMAddIns.Item(ref addInName);
dynamic yourObject = addIn.Object;
bool t = yourObject.DoSomething();


Thank you, adding the dynamic piece solved the issue and allowed it to process through.  That wasn't in any of the examples I came across.
